# TypeScript function accept variadic argument pairs

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible in TypeScript to type a function signature so that the function accepts a flat list of spread tuple arguments? Wow, this is hard to describe using words. Example:

```js
type Pair = { type: string, value: number };

function makePairs(
  t1: string, v1: number,
  t2: string, v2: number,
  ...and_so_on: unknown
): Pair[] {
  // ...
}

makePairs('a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3);
// => [
//   { type: 'a', value: 1 },
//   { type: 'b', value: 2 },
//   { type: 'c', value: 3 },
// ]
```

I'm not interested in the implementation of the function body, just to be clear - just in converting a tuple like `[A, B]` into a variadic tuple like `[A, B, A, B, A, B, ...]`.

Step two of the problem is to make it work with a slightly more complicated definition of `Pair`, e.g.:

```js
type StrPair = { type: 's', value: string };
type IntPair = { type: 'i', value: number };
type BoolPair = { type: 'b', value: boolean };
type Pair = StrPair | IntPair | BoolPair;

type PairType = Pair['type'];
// => 's' | 'i' | 'b'

type PairOfType<T extends PairType> =
  | (T extends 's' ? StrPair : never)
  | (T extends 'i' ? IntPair : never)
  | (T extends 'b' ? BoolPair : never);
// => PairOfType<'s'> === StrPair

type ValueOfType<T extends PairType> = PairOfType<T>['value'];
// => ValueOfType<'s'> === string

type PairTuple<T extends PairType> = [T, ValueOfType<T>];
// => ['i', 123] ✓
//    ['s', 'foo'] ✓
//    ['b', 'nope'] ⨉
// etc

// Now I'd like to be able to take something (conceptually) like this:
function makePairs(...t1: PairTuple, ...t2: PairTuple, ...moreTuples: unknown) {
  // ...
}

// And generalise to something like this:
function makePairs(...pairs: ...[...PairTuple[]]) {
  // ...
}

// ... but obviously neither of those syntaxes work
```

Essentially, I'd like to avoid having to wrap each pair in an array when calling the function, as that seems like unnecessary overhead (trust me, where this will be used, the overhead *would* be significant).

Any ideas?

Comment: [Black magic](https://tsplay.dev/m33Rqm)

Comment: How long do you expect these input lists to be?  The answer will drive how recursive the approach needs to be

Comment: I imagine that [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) will play a role, but I haven't been able to figure it out for this use-case yet.

Comment: So far I have [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXzZLm) which uses some of what @vera. was doing; it's hard to get things to keep inferring string literals instead of `string` when inference starts to go wrong.  I think we need use cases and an idea of how long the input lists will be to give you the best experience.  Are they expected to be less than 10? 100? 1000?

Comment: Thanks everybody! I don't expect the function would be called with more than 20 pairs - it's supposed to be a shortcut for when one needs to compose multiple pairs of values, but it would be used manually, so it's very unlikely to reach even that many, much less hundreds.

Comment: In that case, if you want the callers to have the best experience, you should probably just generate 20 overloads and hide them away in a library as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5ORZW); notice how the errors when callers get things wrong are very explanatory (compared to relatively confusing messages about `never` you tend to get with recursive conditional types).   Does that meet your needs? If so I could write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yeah, that's what I have now basically, but it's ugly, and I thought that since we have recursive conditionals and tuple spreads and whatnot, maybe it could be improved.. but you're right that the error messages it generates are the best out of all the options currently, with the exception of @vera's, which seems flawless, if more than a little magical :D

Comment: Currently vera's version accepts odd numbers of arguments and complains about `never` if you put a non `PairType` argument, and it doesn't give IntelliSense hints.  I don't know if you consider that "flawless" or not.  Maybe those issues could be fixed, but in my experience, the inference you're relying on is involving string literals in variadic recursive conditional tuple types is fragile.  How do you want to proceed with the answer to this question?

Comment: Huh, in that case never mind, I've only checked it in the playground, and even there apparently not very well.. I'm gonna accept @JDB's answer. Thanks again everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preparation

### Treat Arguments as a Big Tuple

It will be helpful to think of the function arguments collection as a large n-tuple. For example, in `makePairs("s", "string", "b", true, "i", 42)`, think of the arguments as the tuple `["s", "string", "b", true, "i", 42]`

### Start With a Generic Type `T`

Because there are potentially infitie variadic tuple combinations that could be assembled for your function, the only way to approach a solution is via a generic type. A generic type allow us to use [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) to build complex, dynamic types from some bedrock first principles.

So, to get started, create a basic generic type `T` that represents an implementation of a variable-length tuple (an "*n-tuple*"):

```js
function makePairs<T extends [any, ...any]>(
  ...args:T,
): void {}
```

- `T extends [any, ...any]` defines a tuple, versus an array, which will make some assertions much easier
- `...args:T` treats the entire argument collection as a tuple

### Build Our Bedrock First Principles

We need some basic tuple types that we can use later to dynamically parse the larger arguments tuple later. This isn't too complex to understand and is pretty close to what you already have:

```js
const t_string = "s" as const;
const t_number = "i" as const;
const t_boolean = "b" as const;
type StrPairTuple = [typeof t_string, string ];
type IntPairTuple = [typeof t_number, number ];
type BoolPairTuple = [typeof t_boolean, boolean ];
type PairTuple = StrPairTuple | IntPairTuple | BoolPairTuple;
```

The important part is the `PairTuple`, which we'll use repeatedly to match function arguments against.

## Enter the Recursive Conditional Type

### Overview

This is where things can start to get a little mind-bending. We'll define a `VariadicTuple` type, but it's important to note that our function signature won't use this type directly. While it represents the heart of our tuple-matching logic, it's also a bit inflexible, so there will be a follow-up `DynamicVariadicTuple` to handle some edge-cases.

This is a large type with many pieces, so let's start with the complete type definition, then break it down:

```js
type VariadicTuple<T extends [any, ...any], PT> =

    // This should always match, but we need the conditional
    // structure in order to infer the first two arguments in the
    // tuple:
    T extends [infer K, infer V, ...infer TT]
    ? [K, V] extends PT

        // If the first two arguments match the TuplePair...
        ? TT extends [any, ...any]
            // ...and there are more arguments, then recurse:
            ? [K, V, ...VariadicTuple<TT, PT>]
            // ...and there are no more arguments, then return:
            : [K, V]

        // If the first two arguments did not match, then return a
        // type that is impossible to match with an embedded error:
        : K extends PT[0]
            ? ["Unrecognized Tuple Value", never]
            : ["Unrecognized Tuple Key", never]

    // This is basically impossible to reach:
    : ["Not enough arguments", never];
```

### Generic Type Arguments

`VariadicTuple` takes two type arguments: `T`, which is a generic n-tuple (`extends [any, ...any]`) and `PT`. `PT` (for "Pair Type") is a type representing valid tuples. For example, to match a variadic tuple of string, number, we'd set `PT` to `[string, number]`. We'll get deeper into this type later.

### Extracting Key, Value and Tail Types

First, we use a conditional type expression to extract the types for the first two elements of the tuple: `K` (for "Key") and `V` (for "Value"). The remaining elements of the tuple (the "tail") are stored in the type `TT` so that they can be used later for recursion:

```js
    T extends [infer K, infer V, ...infer TT]
    ? ...
```

We needed to use a conditional expression to extract `K`, `V` and `TT`, and conditional expressions require an else, even though this one is impossible to reach. Here it is anyway:

```js
    : ["Not enough arguments", never];
```

### Testing If Key and Value Are Valid

Once that boiler-plate expression is out of the way, we can begin the actual testing of the types. This is where we can compare the types `K` and `V` against the expected 2-tuple, `PT`:

```js
    ... [K, V] extends PT
        ? ...

        : K extends PT[0]
            ? ["Unrecognized Tuple Value", never]
            : ["Unrecognized Tuple Key", never]
```

If `[K, V]` does not extend `PT`, then we have an invalid tuple pair. It might be tempting to simply resolve to `never` or something similar at this point, but this would throw off the rest of our type, causing the entire type match to fail. If that happens, then the entire argument collection would be considered in error, rather than the specific argument that is causing the problem.

So instead, we return an unmatchable tuple. While not exactly a standard type error, this will nonetheless help to point out the specific element which is incorrectly typed, whether it's the first element of the fifty-first.

### Recursion

If the tuple is valid, then we need to validate the remaining elements. Fortunately, TypeScript support type recursion and we stored our "tail" in the type `TT`, so all we need to do is check if recursion is required and then either recurse or stop here:

```js
        ... TT extends [any, ...any]
            ? [K, V, ...VariadicTuple<TT, PT>]
            : [K, V]
```

## Putting `VariadicTuple` and `PairTuple` Together

### The Function Definition

Let's start with the function definition. We construct a generic type which must be an n-tuple. We must use a conditional type expression in order to extract the `T` type dynamically, but we'll use the `VariadicTuple<T, PairTuple>` regardless of the outcome:

```js
function makeComplexPairs<T extends [any, ...any]>(...args:T extends VariadicTuple<T, PairTuple> ? T : VariadicTuple<T, PairTuple>):void {}
```

### Results

```js
// Success
makeComplexPairs(t_number, 1, t_boolean, true);

// Success
makeComplexPairs(t_string, "1", t_number, 1, t_number, 4); 

// Error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
makeComplexPairs("g");

// Error:
makeComplexPairs("h", 107);
//               ^ Argument of type '"h"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Unrecognized Tuple Key"'.

// Error:
makeComplexPairs("i", 107, "b", true);
//                         ^ Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Unrecognized Tuple Key"'.

// Success: 'as const' is required because 'infer'
//          changes type "b" to type string
makeComplexPairs("i", 107, "b" as const, true);

// Error:
makeComplexPairs("i", 107, "b" as const, "bad");
//                         ^ Argument of type '"b"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Unrecognized Tuple Value"'.
```

## Working With Dynamic Variadic Tuples

### Constructing a Helper Type and Function Definition

The `PT` type can be determined dynamically based on the first two arguments provided to the function. To make this easier to define, I've created a help type named `DynamicVariadicTuple`. It's job is just to handle the first two elements of a tuple, and then use those elements as the 2-tuple for `PT` in the `VariadicTuple` type. Note that we still need to use a conditional expression to extract `K`, `V` and `TT`, even though it will always succeed:

```js
type DynamicVariadicTuple<T extends [any, ...any]> =
    T extends [infer K, infer V, ...infer TT]
    ? TT extends [any, ...any[]]
        ? [K, V, ...VariadicTuple<TT, [K, V]>]
        : [K, V]
    : ["Not enough arguments", never];
```

The function definition is basically the same as above:

```js
function makeSimplePairs<T extends [any, ...any]>(...args:T extends DynamicVariadicTuple<T> ? T : DynamicVariadicTuple<T>): void {
}
```

### Results

```js
// Success: 'infer' changes consts to simpler types,
//          like string, so we need to be explicit
//          with the first argument
makeSimplePairs("abc" as string, 123, "abc", 456);

// Success:
makeSimplePairs("ab" + "c", 123, "abc", 456);

// Success:
let abc = "abc";
makeSimplePairs(abc, 123, "def", 456);

// Error:
makeSimplePairs(abc, 123, "def", true);
//                        ^ Argument of type '"def"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Unrecognized Tuple Value"'.

// Error:
makeSimplePairs(abc, 123, "def", 456, 789, 1000);
//                                    ^ Argument of type '789' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Unrecognized Tuple Key"'.
```

## Additional Notes

### Type Inference Inconsistencies

There appears to be a subtle incongruity between how TypeScript infers generic types for function arguments and how it infers types in a conditional type. In the former, it takes the most narrow definition, while in the latter it seems to prefer a more general definition.

For example, if the first argument passed to `makeSimplePairs()` is `"abc"` (as depicted above), then the inferred type is the literal string `"abc"`, which means every other argument will also need to be `"abc"`. If you intend for this to be a string, then you'll need to make it more generic by casting (`as string`) or some other means (e.g. a variable , `let abc = "abc"`, or an operation, `"ab" + "c"`).

This also impacts the `makeComplexPairs()` function. While the first argument is correctly read as a literal (e.g. `"i"`, `"s"` or `"b"`), all following arguments are read as more generic types (e.g. `string`), so you'll need to use either a strictly typed variable or the `as const` keyword.

Comment: Thanks @JDB, but if I understand correctly, this only works insofar as it's one tuple being repeated, correct? That is, it won't cover the second case in my question where `B` in the tuple `[A, B]` depends on `A`?

Comment: @DanKadera - I think I've cracked it for both of your use-cases.